# Javascript regex insensitive turkish character issue

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, case-sensitive, turkish

i'm using regex for filtering some contents.

```
var word = new RegExp(filterWord,"gi");// "gi" means Global and insensitive
content = content.replace(word, "");//removes "word" from content
```

This code works properly but when regex get uppercase "İ" it dont replace word.

ex:
if

```
filterWord = istanbul
```

and

```
content = "İstanbul";
```

Above code not working properly , if i write istanbul to İstanbul ,it is working but this time it is not insensitive , how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How **regEx** works with **Small-Case and Upper-Case** chars is based on the Hex-Code of the characters and how they are represented in Unicode consortium of that Unicode set(any language, I hope so as Unicode are based on International Standards).

**eg: For English**

[image: English]

**Similarly, we have**

[image: Turkish]

Above are some highlighted characters with same colors are Upper and Small Case representation of their own and there is only **one difference** in their Hex-code.
for **Ê** Hex-Code is **00CA** and for **ê** is **00EA** with one diffrence
**C** and **E** at **third position**.

Similarly for
**Ý** and **ý**
Hex-Code is **00DD** and **u00FD** with one difference **D** and **F**

Now check this eg:

```
'ÊÌÝêìý'.match(/Ì/gi) //case insensitive
//output ["Ì", "ì"]
'ÊÌÝêìý'.match(/Ì/g) //case sensitive
//output ["Ì"]

'ÊÌÝêìý'.match(/Ý/ig) //case insensitive
//output ["Ý", "ý"]
'ÊÌÝêìý'.match(/Ý/g) //case sensitive
//output ["Ý"]
```

If you are using right Characters then it should work normally. **I don't know much about Latin-Turkish Characters.**

Comment: its really good explanation of characters hex-codes , i think "i" and "İ" do not similar with Ì and ì , turkish a bit different unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

you can express lower and upper cases in a bracket

/[İi]stanbul/i

you can see from [here](https://regex101.com/r/bFJSfM/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is subject of **Unicode** characters.

What happens is that `i` in your example is not a single letter but 2 because the tilde counts as a character as well. This brings lots of complexities and rules that needs to be followed in order to meet Unicode rules.

You could do something like: `([\x{0049}-\x{0130}])` to meet your *i* needs but this expression may vary depending if you are going to use this expression on .net, java, javascript or php.

*[*Online Demo*](http://regex101.com/r/lL8zN5)*

You could also check what code each character represents here:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=%C4%B0&preview=entity